Firebase Firestore is missing loadbundle and namedQuery method
This is my code, however, the Firebase function project is complaining that loadBundle and namedQuery methods are missing.
My package.json has the latest versions. How can I resolve this?
"dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^12.1.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.9.0",
    "googleapis": "^115.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "node-apple-receipt-verify": "^1.12.1"
  },



You cannot call the loadBundle() nor the namedQuery() function on a Firestore object because there are no such functions present inside the Firestore class. What I think you're looking for is called bundle() which:

Creates a new BundleBuilder instance to package selected Firestore data into a bundle.

One thing to mention is that those functions are present if you're using Data Bundles in React Native and not when using the Admin SDK.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/serve-bundles
I am simply trying to follow what is here. But I cannot see those methods.

And I am implementing firebase function not a webclient, maybe I misunderstood, so a firebase function cannot call another functoin or get it from CDN and load the bundle?

Yes, that is the reason why those functions are not present. Those functions are present only for web (client) applications and can help fetch the bundled content from the CDN and load it into the Firestore SDK.

Is there a way to load bundles using Flutter app?

Yes, you can use loadBundle in your Flutter app.
